# UI5 Application

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to integrate my application in to another application but having issues with folders not being found, the application works fine as a standalone so it's something to do with mapping I was hoping someone could help me.

So application A has a folder called models and in models we have a `icons.json`. When application a is run it recognizes this folder and the JSON so everything is fine.

We call application A from application B, but now application A is looking for folder models in Application B and it can't find it.

Is there a way to make the application only look with in itself and not the calling application?

TIA.

Comment: I suggest you browse the directories available by using your browser debugging tools. You might see how the path has changed there.

Comment: I can see the structure but, the application isn't actually loading all the folders, and then its also pointing to the main application.

So it looks like:

sap - bc/ui5_ui5/sap - Application A & Application B under that.

Comment: What do you mean with "integrate" ?

Comment: If integrating means embedding as a component, all applications have their own manifests where the folder structures and namespaces are defined, and then used in the require style controllers and controls. It's impossible to tell what to do with your particular problem without seeing some code. In the meantime here's a [decent resource](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/10/23/demystifying-the-art-of-component-reuse-in-sapui5/) on that

Comment: Yes that is what I meant, so I have this line of code:

var scenarioIcons = new JSONModel();
scenarioIcons.loadData("model/scenarioIcons.json", null, false);

But it is looking in the applicationB/model...... rather than applicationA/model. I've tried putting the full file path, dots forward slashes etc all before it and I just can't seem to get it to work.